# Which is correct, since or from in the given context?

Tags: word-choice

Context:
1: I have been working "since" July. 
2: I have been working "from" July. 
If not from, then why ?

Answer (score 1):

Use "from" when you are talking about a range of time that does not continue up until the present:

> I worked from July until September.

Use since if the time range started on the past and continues through the present:

> I have been working since July.

Note that the tense changes from the past simple to the present perfect continuous tense to account for the fact that the activity is ongoing.

Comment: Past perfect or past perfect continuous?

Comment: @user Good catch. I went and double checked. It's actually present perfect continuous.